# How do I add an HTML attribute to row (WP Bakery Visual Composer)?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add an ID attribute to row in Visual Composer via documented function `vc_add_param()` in such a way:

```
$attributes = array(
 'type' => 'textfield',
 'heading' => "HTML ID",
 'param_name' => 'el_id',
 'value' => '',
 'description' => __( "Assign an ID to the row", "discprofile" )
);
vc_add_param( 'vc_row', $attributes );
```

ID field appears when I edit a row. I set a value, save it, save page, view it, but there is no affect to frontend. A row still has no ID attribute.

I've also tried use `'param_name' => 'id'` and `'param_name' => 'element_id'`, it was the same. What is wrong?

Comment: Ask at http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/support

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

We have to remap a shortcode and change its template to add additional parameters.

So, in my case:

```
// Add custom row options

    function change_vc_rows() {

        // Add parameters we want
        vc_add_param('vc_row', array(
            'type' => 'textfield',
            'heading' => "HTML ID",
            'param_name' => 'element_id',
            'value' => '',
            'description' => __("Assign an ID to the row", "discprofile")
        ));

        // Update 'vc_row' to include custom vc_row template and remap shortcode
        $new_map = vc_map_update( 'vc_row', array('html_template' => locate_template('templates/vc_row.php')) );

        // Remove default vc_row
        vc_remove_element('vc_row');

        // Remap shortcode with custom template
        vc_map($new_map['vc_row']);
    }

    // Include our function when all wordpress stuff is loaded
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'change_vc_rows' );
```

We included templates/vc_rows.php file. It is the row template file, copied from plugins/js_composer/include/templates/shortcodes/vc_rows.php with some changes. Here it is:

```
<?php
/** @var $this WPBakeryShortCode_VC_Row */
// $element_id was added to output
$output = $element_id = $el_class = $bg_image = $bg_color = $bg_image_repeat = $font_color = $padding = $margin_bottom = $css = $full_width = '';
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    // added element_id attribute
    'element_id' => '',
    'el_class' => '',
    'bg_image' => '',
    'bg_color' => '',
    'bg_image_repeat' => '',
    'font_color' => '',
    'padding' => '',
    'margin_bottom' => '',
    'full_width' => false,
    'css' => '',
), $atts ) );

// wp_enqueue_style( 'js_composer_front' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpb_composer_front_js' );
// wp_enqueue_style('js_composer_custom_css');

$el_class = $this->getExtraClass( $el_class );

$css_class = apply_filters( VC_SHORTCODE_CUSTOM_CSS_FILTER_TAG, 'vc_row wpb_row ' . ( $this->settings( 'base' ) === 'vc_row_inner' ? 'vc_inner ' : '' ) . get_row_css_class() . $el_class . vc_shortcode_custom_css_class( $css, ' ' ), $this->settings['base'], $atts );

$style = $this->buildStyle( $bg_image, $bg_color, $bg_image_repeat, $font_color, $padding, $margin_bottom );
?>

<!-- Added an ID attribute where we echo our $element_id variable -->
<div <?php
    ?>class="<?php echo esc_attr( $css_class ); ?><?php if ( $full_width == 'stretch_row_content_no_spaces' ): echo ' vc_row-no-padding'; endif; ?>" id="<?php echo $element_id; ?>" <?php if ( ! empty( $full_width ) ) {
    echo ' data-vc-full-width="true"';
    if ( $full_width == 'stretch_row_content' || $full_width == 'stretch_row_content_no_spaces' ) {
        echo ' data-vc-stretch-content="true"';
    }
} ?> <?php echo $style; ?>><?php
echo wpb_js_remove_wpautop( $content );
?></div><?php echo $this->endBlockComment( 'row' );
echo '<div class="vc_row-full-width"></div>';
```

Comment: `vc_map_update()` seems to return `1` rather than the map. So later `vc_map($new_map['vc_row'])` will raise an error after not finding the `base` parameter.

Comment: @Pranab Getting the same error. Were you able to fix it?